# Json file load in hive skipping row1

Tags: json, hadoop, null, hive, header

I am trying to use a single JSON array file in hive using native functions, somehow when its loaded in hive the first row is converted to NULL and 1st row data is lost. Please advise what am I doing incorrect?

Data:

```
[{"id":1,"first_name":"Alexandrina","email":"abalding0@goo.ne.jp","date":"9/11/2016","country":"Nigeria"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Craggie","email":"ctremain1@photobucket.com","date":"12/7/2016","country":"China"},
{"id":3,"first_name":"Allie","email":"adearan2@ycombinator.com","date":"10/31/2016","country":"Russia"},
{"id":30,"first_name":"Vinson","email":"vplumbleyt@hubpages.com","date":"5/16/2016","country":"Saint Kitts and Nevis"}]
```

**Hive function:**

```
CREATE TABLE format.json_table (json string);
LOAD DATA INPATH  '/user/cloudera/JSON/MOCK_DATA.json' INTO TABLE json_table;
```

*When I query:*

```
select get_json_object(json_table.json, '$.id') as id,
get_json_object(json_table.json, '$.first_name') as name,
get_json_object(json_table.json, '$.email') as email,
get_json_object(json_table.json, '$.date') as date,
get_json_object(json_table.json, '$.country') as country from json_table;
```

**it returns**

```
OK
id  name    email   date    country
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2   Craggie ctremain1@photobucket.com   12/7/2016   China
3   Allie   adearan2@ycombinator.com    10/31/2016  Russia
4   Poul    psondland3@mlb.com  9/11/2016   Nigeria
5   Vinson  vplumbleyt@hubpages.com 5/16/2016   Saint Kitts and Nevis
```

Comment: There is no way these are the results from this query.

Comment: you will get only one Row as NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL from this query

Comment: Well it is my output :)

Comment: You do realize that you don't have id 4 and 5 in your data sample

Answer (score 0):

JSON SerDe works with single line documents.
Given your data, every line that is by itself a valid JSON documents is appropriately read and every row that isn't fails the JSON parser, causing NULL values to be returned.